# GROUP_CONCAT in IN Subquery

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT  A.id, A.title, 
FROM (`table`) as A
WHERE A.active = '1'
AND A.id IN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(B.id) from B where user = 3)
```

If i launch subquery `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(B.id) from B where user = 3` only, i obtain 1,2,3,4. But if i launch entire query i obtain only one row.

But if i try to substitute the subquery with its value (1,2,3,4)

```
SELECT  A.id, A.title, 
FROM (`table`) as A
WHERE A.active = '1'
AND A.id IN (1,2,3,4)
```

i obtain the 4 rows ... as i need.

Where is my error ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MySQL is seeing the subquery return only a single field/row, and therefore treats it as something like:

```
... and A.id IN ('1,2,3,4')
```

which boils down to `A.id = '1,2,3,4'`.

For an 'in' query, there's no need for the group_concat stuff, simply do:

```
... and A.id IN (select B.id FROM b where user = 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name
FROM test
WHERE salry
IN (

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT('''', salry,'''' ) ) 
FROM test group by salry
)
```

this concat will append the resultset with single quotes still its not working  like salry will be in resultset `'1000','2000','3000','40000'` ...

Answer (score 0):

Use `FIND_IN_SET()`

```
SELECT  A.id, A.title, 
FROM (`table`) as A
WHERE A.active = '1'
AND FIND_IN_SET(A.id,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(B.id) from B where user = 3))
```